# displaying questions with 4 options on php?

Tags: php, mysql

I fetched questions and options from the database using while loop and showed on the page using php. But i can select only one option on the whole page.

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_m)){

```
        echo"<section>";
            $j=2;
        echo "<tr>"."<td>".$row[q_id]."</td><td colspan=".$j.">".$row[question]."</td></tr>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td></td>";
        echo"<td><input type=radio name=same id=same/>" .$row[option1]."</td>";
        echo"<td><input type=radio name=same id=same/>".$row[option2]."</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo"<td><input type=radio name=same id=same/>".$row[option3]."</td>";
        echo"<td><input type=radio name=same id=same/>".$row[option4]."</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo"<tr><td></td>";

        echo"</section>";
```

Comment: It would be very helpful for you to include the code for the while loop that displays the questions and options.

Comment: i have included...can you please help me now...

Answer (score 0):

Use different name for different groups

```
$i=1;
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_m)){
 echo"<section>";
        $j=2;
    echo "<tr>"."<td>".$row[q_id]."</td><td colspan=".$j.">".$row[question]."</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td></td>";
    echo"<td><input type=radio name=".$i." id=".$row[option1]."/>" .$row[option1]."</td>";
    echo"<td><input type=radio name=".$i." id=".$row[option2]."/>".$row[option2]."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo"<td><input type=radio name=".$i." id=".$row[option3]."/>".$row[option3]."</td>";
    echo"<td><input type=radio name=".$i." id=".$row[option4]."/>".$row[option4]."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"<tr><td></td>";

    echo"</section>"; 
    $i++;

}
```